# Reading TCP Stream from TShark without Bytes in Packet

Tags: wireshark

I'm using TShark to read in existing `*.pcap` and `*.pcapng` files.  When I output the TCPStream as an ASCII string using `-z follow,tcp,ascii,33` (for stream number 33), I see all the ASCII data, but I also see that between packets, the ASCII stream is split by the the size of that packet in Bytes.

So, an example of the TCP Stream is below.  The first half before the number is in one packet, followed by the remaining data found in a different template.

"website.templ

842

tes.output/name"

Assuming that I'm trying to regex on "templates" in this TCPStream, this split causes the regex to miss this occurrence of "templates" because it's split between two different packets.

Is there anyway to export the TCPStream as ASCII without the bytes field?

I attempted to use the `-o` flag to change the default setting of `tcp.track_bytes_in_flight`, but this only applies to live captures vs what I'm doing, analyzing static files.

Comment: Might be a better fit on [networkengineering.se]

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I'll post over there as well.